# How learn/detect the error/offset pattern with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, error-handling, offset, prediction, data-analysis

Is there a chance to use **Machine Learning Tools/Techniques** to **analyze** the **offset/error** of true value from existing **Prediction Model** ?
The techniques to **learn/detect** the **error pattern**, which could give a clue about the situation where Prediction model cannot cover?

Comment: yes there is. read about boosting methods like gradient boosting.

Comment: ok thanks Clock Slave I will read about boosting methods.                         Small notaion: Is the BM valid/works if I just have the predicted data and true data, e.g. just two curves?

Comment: Generally we use the fitted data as well. But I cant say thats not possible. you might get it to work if you hack around